# How to you print the index or get the item of a item in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

So I'm making a program that makes random phone numbers. I've made an `ArrayList` of these phone numbers and I want to be able to search through my `ArrayList` and find the number (if it exists) and print both the index of it and the data contained.

Here is what I've gotten so far:

```
  public static ArrayList<String>phoneList = new ArrayList<String>();

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner s = new Scanner();

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      phoneList.add(getPhoneNumber()); //getPhoneNumber returns a random phoneNumber
    }

    System.out.print("Enter Phone Number: ");
    String enteredNumber = s.nextLine();

    if(phoneList.containts(enteredNumber)){ 
      //tell me the index of that phone number in the list and
      //print out the phone number
    }



  }
```

I want to know how to do what's in the if statement.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `indexOf(Object)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(phoneList.contains(enteredNumber)
{
     int index= phoneList.indexOf(enteredNumber);
     String number = phoneList.get(index);
}
```

This will give the index of that Number in the list  as well as Number.

Answer (score 1):

Simply iterate through that list.

```
for(int i=0; i<phoneList.size(); i++){
   if(phoneList.get(i).equals(phoneNumber)){
       System.out.println("Index: "+i);
       System.out.println("PhoneNumber: "+phoneNumber);
       break;
   }
}
```